# Bar chart in R from a factor with two variables

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have calculated a weighted average of a subset with the following code:

```
regionsales <- ddply(d, ~Region, summarize, weighted.mean(sales, w=size)
```

This gives me a factor with two variables and five observation:

```
Region    Sales
1         34
2         87
3         92
4         103
5         29
```

I want to make a bar chart in R, where the x-axis is the region number and y-axis is the number of (averaged) sales. I have tried with:

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(
x = regionsales$Region,
y = regionsales$Sales,
name = "Sales",
type = "bar")
```

But it does not work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: That works - you just need to display p - type `p` or `print(p)` at the console.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One question: How do I sort "Sales", so region 4 is the first one, number 3 the second one etc.?

Comment: Run this first - `regionsales$Region <- factor(regionsales$Region,levels = order(-regionsales$Sales))` and then the code you have.  That will set `Region` to be an ordered factor sorted according to decreasing `sales` (or, more precisely, increasing `-sales`).